# Return bool value in matlab

Tags: matlab

how the user defined function return bool value(true/false) in mat lab?
e.g as in any high level language:

```
bool function_name(int param 1, int param 2) {
  if(param 1 < param 2)
    return true;
  else  
    return false;
}
```

I want to ask that how a function in mat lab return a bool value?

Comment: "How do I do ___ in matlab?" ... proceeds to tag every language except matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The general format of a function in MATLAB is the following:

```
function boolAnswer = function_name( param1, param2 )
boolAnswer = (param1 < param2);
```

I can then call this function later in some other code like so:

```
newAnswer = function_name(x, y)
```